# CSS for Table in Wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress, class

I am trying to add custom css to a certain table in Wordpress.

However it seems that the default css is overwriting it perhaps?

```
<table id="2table" border="0" cellspacing="3" cellpadding="3">
```

CSS:

```
table#2table {
       margin-left: 450px auto;
       margin-top: -205px auto;
}
```

Comment: why auto has been given beside margin0left and margin-right values? There should be single value assigned to these properties.

Comment: cellspacing and cellpadding should be handled in CSSm and id and classnames should never start with a digit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IDs mustn't start with a number.

Change your `id="2table"` to something else like `id="table2"`, then adjust your CSS accordingly.